# How i can send email by using gpg tools?

Tags: windows, email, windows-xp

I downloaded GPG tools to my computer (Windows XP), read about it and then I did the following:

1. Install tool
2. Generate public and private keys
3. Import public key
4. Export public key
5. Encrypt file
6. Decrypt file

But now I want to know how I can send e-mail by using GPG tools? Does GPG support sending email or I should be using other software?

Answer (score 3):

You could use Thunderbird and Enigmail. gpg is **not** about sending mails.